# Mime content type for gpx not recognized with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have an app in rails 4.26 and ruby 2.3.1 with paperclip 4.3.6, firefox and Ubuntu 14.0.4 64 that i use to upload a gpx file with the code

```
validates_attachment_content_type :gpx, :content_type => { content_type: 'application/xml'
```

also tried with

```
validates_attachment_content_type :gpx, :content_type => { content_type: 'application/gpx+xml' }
```

in my Track model but doesn't pass the validation with a valid gpx file.

If I validate by name extension like

```
validates_attachment_file_name :gpx, matches: /gpx\Z/
```

loads fine.

When I run the file command:

```
$ file demofilelite.gpx --mime-type -b
```

I get
application/xml
as output

I tried using a paperclip.rb file in config/initializers with

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { gpx: %w(application/xml) }
```

But it didn't work either.
How do I make paperclip recognize a gpx file byt mime content?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working with this validation in my track.rb model file:

```
validates :gpx, presence: true, attachment_content_type: { content_type: ["application/gpx+xml","text/xml","application/xml","application/octet-stream"] }
```

That is a different header for Edge, chrome and firefox.
And the create an initializar in config/initializers/paperclip.rb with:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { :gpx => ["application/xml"] }
```

To deal with the file command response.
This will load gpx and xml files. If you only want gpx you have to add another validation to your model:

```
validates_attachment_file_name :gpx, matches: /gpx\Z/
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can try to put this line in your 
>   confing/initilizer/mime_type.rb
>
> Mime::Type.register "application/gpx", :gpx

Comment: That solves partially the problem with the anti-spoofing engine but it doesn't work because as it turns out every browser sends different types of mime headers for a gpx file